# What is MVE an abreviation for?

Tags: definition

I tried searching but neither google nor stackexchange gave me anything. I can almost infer that MVE is the header file of a latex document but I see some examples that include the header the body and the footer. At no point did I find any search results that explain what M.V.E. is an abbreviation for. I got some hints that E is for environment. Please correct me if I am wrong. What is MVE both in name and in definition?

Comment: Do you mean MWE? That is a "minimal working example", see e.g. https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ In essence, the smallest complete document you can make to illustrate a problem.

Comment: If you did mean MVE not MWE, then that is not a well known acronym, please give a link to where you have seen it used and someone will say what it means in that context

Answer (score 4):

You don’t link to an example, but from context: I would guess it’s a mash-up of what TeX StackExchange calls a MWE (Minimal Working Example) and StackOverflow calls a MCVE (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example).  Or as Lewis Carroll put it:

> Supposing that, when Pistol uttered the well-known words—‘Under which king, Bezonian? Speak or die!’ Justice Shallow had felt certain that it was either William or Richard, but had not been able to settle which, so that he could not possibly say either name before the other, can it be doubted that, rather than die, he would have gasped out ‘Rilchiam!’